# display url in WKWebView when partially loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have recently started working with WKWebViews.  When loading a url the WKWebView appears to wait for all javascript to complete before it shows any of the page.  Is there a way to allow the WKWebView to load content progressively like it does in a UIWebView.  Thanks